# What is the proper way to use UBOs(uniform buffer objects) with regards to per-draw-call data. (OpenGL/C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

So I've just started transitioning my code base over to using uniform buffer objects. So far I've been able to get UBOs working for things that are shared across multiple shader programs like cameras.

Now I also read that using UBOs was a good idea for per drawcall data such as the model matrix, materials, bones, etc.

That said I'm having trouble digging up information on the "best/proper" approach to this.

A few of the layouts I am considering (though they may not be on the right path, please correct me if this is the case) are:

A:
Have the global data (camera etc) in one ubo with its own block.
Have the each independant set of drawcall data its own blocks.

so basically

one ubo / block for:

```
layout (std140) uniform camera_ubo {
    mat4 camera stuff... etc
};
```

one ubo / block for:

```
layout (std140) uniform mesh_ubo {
    mat4 bones[MAX_BONES];
    etc...
};
```

then I use the `glBufferSubData` just before each draw-call to update the values.

B: Push everything into one ubo block and again use `glBufferSubData` on the parts that actually need to be updated per drawcall.

C: Something completely different because the above options are terrible. (If so what?)

PS: If the answer depends on glMapBuffer at all, it's not something I "should" use one the platform I'm targeting as it would need to be emulated creating a performance hit.

Edit: I've implemented the "A" example, works fine, but then it got me thinking, if I have lets say a "material" ubo, and that material has properties like color, roughness, etc. I i would need to update the gpu side "material" to reflect the one being used on the cpu side, each time it changes, now obviously you could batch the materials, but I was thinking, should each material be a ubo so each mat only needs to be passed to the gpu once(then you run out of UBOs quickly), or should I have some sort of materials ubo that contains an array of material structs, because if I understand it correctly, the amount of data each UBO can hold is quite substantial. This idea could be applied to the "mesh_ubo" described above, something like:

```
struct mesh {
    layout (std140) uniform mesh_ubo {
    mat4 bones[MAX_BONES];
    etc...
};

layout (std140) uniform meshs_ubo {
    mesh meshes[MAX_MESHES];
};
```

Anyway, same question stands, I am still looking for the "right way" to package all this stuff up. Because currently I'm seeing a lot of things that look like they will work fine in very simple use-cases with small amounts of data, but possibly will break down once I scale everything up.

Comment: I don't think there will be a big performance difference between A and B, but in the end the only way to be sure is to implement both and test it. There are too many unknowns to give you a better answer. Buffer mappings might give you a performance boost but that depends mainly on how the data is accessed and whether this can be improved by manual synchronization.